# Can we extract dictionary from pandas dataframe in a certain format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

trying to get dataframe value to extract in a specific format in the documentation I read about to_dict but it's not giving me exact o/p. is there any way to serialize df data efficiently.

data used to create dataframe

```
data = [{'customer': 'XYZ', 'company': 'aditya', 'source_scheme': 'aditya', 'target_scheme': None, 'folio_no': '100', 'units': Decimal('0.000000'), 'market_value': 70.606, 'stp_amount': Decimal('1000.000000'), 'frequency': 'M', 'stp_start_date': datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 6, 0, 0), 'stp_end_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 21, 0, 0), 'stp_due_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 21, 0, 0), 'stp_ref_no': '191796'}, {'customer': 'XYZ', 'company': 'aditya', 'source_scheme': 'aditya', 'target_scheme': None, 'folio_no': '100', 'units': Decimal('0.000000'), 'market_value': 70.606, 'stp_amount': Decimal('4000.000000'), 'frequency': 'M', 'stp_start_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 12, 0, 0), 'stp_end_date': datetime.datetime(2040, 12, 28, 0, 0), 'stp_due_date': datetime.datetime(2040, 12, 28, 0, 0), 'stp_ref_no': '204243'}, {'customer': 'XYZ', 'company': 'aditya', 'source_scheme': 'aditya', 'target_scheme': None, 'folio_no': '100', 'units': Decimal('0.000000'), 'market_value': 70.606, 'stp_amount': Decimal('1000.000000'), 'frequency': 'M', 'stp_start_date': datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 6, 0, 0), 'stp_end_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 21, 0, 0), 'stp_due_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 21, 0, 0), 'stp_ref_no': '191796'}, {'customer': 'XYZ', 'company': 'aditya', 'source_scheme': 'aditya', 'target_scheme': None, 'folio_no': '100', 'units': Decimal('0.000000'), 'market_value': 70.606, 'stp_amount': Decimal('4000.000000'), 'frequency': 'M', 'stp_start_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 12, 0, 0), 'stp_end_date': datetime.datetime(2040, 12, 28, 0, 0), 'stp_due_date': datetime.datetime(2040, 12, 28, 0, 0), 'stp_ref_no': '204243'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_dict('records')
```

o/p expected

```
{
    'rows':[
        {
            'cells': [
                {'type': 'text', 'value': 'xyz'}, 
                {'type': 'number', 'value': 20094.62}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

in this o/p will convert each cell of dataframe rows to this format anything small is also helpful thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the input map to the output? Some of the keys don’t exist

Comment: keys we can provide in some kind of schema and we just have to put value and value type in its place...i am not sure how it can achieve it with dataframes I did it before with dictionary & marshmallow @enke